# Angular - Unable to fetch data from api

Tags: angular

**Error:**

> GET https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v1/entries/en/hi 403
>   (Forbidden).

xyz.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class XyzService {

   word: String = "aardvark";
   constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}
   private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
   console.log(err.message);
   return Observable.throw(err.message);
  }
   getDictonaryData(name?): any {
       if(name){
          this.word = name
      }

  let headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.append('Accept','application/json');
  headers.append('app_id','4e**91');
  headers.append('app_key','7d0740a128b****843d6f');

  let myResponse = this._http.get('https://od- 
  api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v1/entries/en/'+this.word,{headers:headers
 });
  return myResponse;

  }
 }
```

app.component.ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
 import { XyzService } from './xyz.service';
 import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
 import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
name:string;
dictData:any;


 constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private 
xyzService: XyzService, ) {}

 getData() {
  this.xyzService.getDictonaryData(this.name).subscribe(
    data => {

        this.dictData = data;
          console.log(this.dictData);
          } ,

      error => {
          console.log("some error occured");
          console.log(error.errorMessage);
      }
   );

  }}
```

app.component.html

```
<input id="name" type="text" [(ngModel)]="name"/>
<button (click)="getData()"> Get Data </button>

<div class="row" *ngIf="dictData">
<h2>{{dictData["results"][0]["lexicalEntries"][0]["entries"][0]["senses"][0] 
["definitions"]}}

</h2>
</div>
```

Earlier I was also getting one more error

> 'No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested
>   resource'.

But after I included 'Moesif Origin & CORS Changer'extension , this error has gone .
But still I am getting another Error:

```
GET https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v1/entries/en/hi 403 (Forbidden).
```

Comment: https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/documentation/response-codes

Comment: First test the API without using Angular (using Fiddler or Swagger for example).

Answer (score 0):

Let try this,

```
httpParams = httpParams.set('params1', paramsValue);
return this.httpClient.get<any>(url, {
      headers: httpHeaders,
      params: httpParams
    });
```

Comment: I am getting few errors . Cannot find name 'httpParams'. Property 'set' does not exist on type 'typeof HttpParams' .

Comment: Do like this man, let httpParams = new HttpParams().set('categoryId', String(categoryId));